# Included a HTTP (not HTTPS) URL link in my iOS App, do I need to disable App Transport Security?

Tags: ios, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

My iOS app included a privacy policy URL link, when users tap on it, it will open a HTTP (not HTTPS) page of my website in Safari, so do I need to disable App Transport Security for this?

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you don't have to disable App Transport Security for opening HTTP URLs with `UIApplication.open(_:)`, nor when you open it within an `SFSafariViewController`.

However, you **do need to enable Allow Arbitrary Loads** if you're planning to load a non-secure page in a `WKWebView`.

Comment: Why WKWebView needs it, but not SFSafariViewController? @Tamás Sengel

Comment: Probably because SFSafariViewController is more secure, by default, compared to WKWebView. To quote Apple: "The user's activity and interaction with SFSafariViewController are not visible to your app, which cannot access AutoFill data, browsing history, or website data."

Comment: Officially, I believe it is because SFSafarViewController is a separate process from your app, so any ATS exceptions configured in your app don't apply to the Safari process.  So it's essentially like loading the non-secure page in Safari, which has no access to your sandboxed app.